# Cancelling A Thread Safely

Tags: c, pthreads

I have C code in main that creates 10 threads. Then I join for those threads.

Each thread goes to a function like this:

```
void test_function(char *findThis)
{
    // do something

    // then something like this
    if message cancel thread?
}
```

The message would probably be a Boolean global variable. How do I cancel the thread afterwards?

Comment: `if (message) return;`

Comment: Simple. Just return from that function.

Comment: :) The simplest answer must be the correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a thread executes a particular function. If you return from that function, it no longer exists.

So, simply return from that function if you want your thread to stop, like this -

```
if (got_my_message) {
    return;
}
```

Of course, you should perform necessary resource clean up (i.e., free up allocated memory) before you do so.

Comment: Thank you. I was over thinking it.

Comment: I guess the 'global boolean variable' should be marked `volatile` also?  (Disclaimer, I've never used threads in my life!)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: You can use a global variable, or you can use other mechanism (sockets?) for inter-thread communication. For simpler ones, you could use global variables, I guess. In that case, yes, it will be better if you mark it as `volatile`.

Comment: @aluminumMonster: When you mark a variable as `volatile`, you are telling the compiler that this variable will be accessed by multiple threads in an unpredictable manner. So it should not perform certain optimizations on it. Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable).